# postgresql: select / update where column-varchar = "numericstring"

Tags: postgresql

I have a table with a field named "reference" `(character varying(255))` to store numbers as strings because some of them are bigger than 20 digits.

But if I try: `SELECT * FROM table WHERE reference = '12345'` there is 0 results.

if I try: `UPDATE table SET some_number = 20 WHERE reference = '12345'` there is 0 results.

why?

Note: no index column in this table

Comment: So the two results seem to be consistent. In both cases there is apparently no row where the column contains that value.

Comment: "*because some of them are bigger than 20 digits*" - then why aren't you using `numeric`? That would be much more efficient than using `varchar`. Storing numbers in a `varchar` column is never a good idea (btw: there is no magic optimization or performance improvement involved in limiting a varchar column to 255)

Comment: @a-horse-with-no-name there is one row with that value

Comment: i didn't know that type, i'm going to try, thanks

Comment: There are probably spaces or other "invisible" characters. `numeric` is the way to go.

Comment: `numeric` works!! Thanks!!! @a_horse_with_no_name